# Работа с github. Как удалить все комиты кроме последнего

Tags: github, git-commit

Вообщем недавно зарегестрировался в github и установил Desktop Github. Довольно-таки удобная вещица, но я незаметил, что он синхронизирует все файлы, это ничего, но это все в открытом доступе. У меня был дамп SQL файла, а там емайл(ы). Вообщем все это в открытом доступе т.е. смотреть могут все.

Вопрос как можно удалить все комиты кроме последнего.

Посмотрев я понял, что нужно игнорировать некоторые файлы и передовать их через флешку. :(

Answer (score 1):

Лучше сразу полностью удалить репозиторий. Потом уже ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО пушить только то что нужно.

Уже были случаи когда парень случайно запушил на гитХаб свои ключики и его хаканали....

и комиты удалять нельзя, это же система контроля версий, сохранять историю изменений - это ее главная обязанность.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте пустую ветку, сделайте в ней коммит с текущими файлами, замените 'master' пустой веткой, и сделате forced-push:

```
git checkout --orphan clean
git commit -m 'Initial commit' -a
git branch -D master
git branch -m clean master
git push -f
```